# Unable to use variable containing string in place of hardcoded string

Tags: javascript, string, stripe-payments

I am setting up Stripe on my web app. Stripe seems to work fine when I hardcode a string such as `'test@test.com'` into the email parameter. When I try to use the value from the input box however, the code does not execute properly. I do not get an error, the code just simply does not execute further. Here is my code:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        var user_email = document.getElementById('example1-email').value;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = user_email;


        event.preventDefault();

        stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
            billing_details: {
                email: user_email
            },
        }).then(stripePaymentMethodHandler);
    });
    function stripePaymentMethodHandler(result, email) {
        if (result.error) {

        } else {
            // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server
            fetch('/checkout_stripe', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: user_email,
                    payment_method: result.paymentMethod.id
                }),
            }).then(function (result) {
                return result.json();
            }).then(function (customer) {
                // The customer has been created
            }).then(redirectfunc);
        }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="subscription-form">
    <div class="cell example example1" id="example-1" style="padding-left: 25%;padding-right: 25%;padding-top: 5%">

        <br>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="example1-name" data-tid="elements_examples.form.name_label">Name</label>
                <input id="example1-name" data-tid="elements_examples.form.name_placeholder" type="text" placeholder="Jane Doe" required
                    autocomplete="name">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="example1-email" data-tid="elements_examples.form.email_label">Email</label>
                <input id="example1-email" data-tid="elements_examples.form.email_placeholder" type="email" placeholder="janedoe@gmail.com"
                    required autocomplete="email">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="example1-phone" data-tid="elements_examples.form.phone_label">Phone</label>
                <input id="example1-phone" data-tid="elements_examples.form.phone_placeholder" type="tel" placeholder="(941) 555-0123" required
                    autocomplete="tel">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="example1-card"></div>
            </div>
            <form id="subscription-form">
                <div id="card-element" class="MyCardElement">
                    <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
                </div>

                <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" style="background-color: #27eb15">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
```

This is just the stock code from Stripe, with me pulling in the string from the input box and trying to put it into the email param. Bizarrely, only a hardcoded string such as `test@test.com` allows the process to complete, but not just using the var `user_email` - despite that just being a string that contains the same string as the hardcoded.

I have tested whether or not I am actually pulling anything in when I use the `.value`, and I am. I have also tested the datatype of `user_email`, and it is indeed a string.

How can I get this to execute properly using the data pulled in from the user input boxes?

Comment: I don't see a problem in your js, please post the HTML form so we can see. Also, it might be a problem of a library such as 'mdbootstrap', so if you have a can link plz comment it and try again.

Comment: @Ess Updated with my HTML. As I mentioned, I have tested whether or not I am pulling anything in from the forms and I am. I also tested the datatype and it is a string... so not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: What happens when you log the value inside `user_email`? What happens if you add a log right after the second line, do you see it?

Comment: @koopajah Yes, it is logged properly. `user_email` contains the string.

Comment: you have `if(result.error)` but then the block is empty. If you log `result.error.message` inside that if statement, is there an error?

Comment: @karllekko So I did find this error message in the console `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: user_email is not defined
    at stripePaymentMethodHandler`

Comment: That seems like the issue then, right? Your user-email variable is only defined inside the form submit function. It's not available inside the entirely separate stripePaymentMethodHandler function. You'd likely want to retrieve it again by doing  `document.getElementById('example1-email').value;` again inside that function, or you can read it from `result.paymentMethod. billing_details.email` there as well I think.

Comment: @karllekko Yes, I eventually discovered this, JS is not my native language. Thank you.